# C++ Protected / Public overloads

Tags: c++, overloading, public, protected

I have a class like this :

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            v.push_back(i);
    };
    const vector<double>& V() const {return v;};
protected:
    vector<double>& V() {return v;};
private:
    vector<double> v;
};
```

And then a piece of code like this :

```
Foo foo;
for(int i = 0; i < (int) foo.V().size(); ++i)
    cout << foo.V().at(i) << endl;
```

However, the latter raises a compilation error saying the `V()` call is a protected method while i am just trying to read from it, not modify it.

I have tried the following (but without success).

```
Foo foo;
const vector<double>& test = foo.V();
for(int i = 0; i < (int) test.size(); ++i)
    cout << test.at(i) << endl;
```

Many thanks for your help.

=====

Thank you all for the explanations and solutions ! It's greatly appreciated !

Comment: what's the point of having a `private` variable if you give away a `protected` reference to it ? (personally, I consider this evil).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to overload on return value. Non-const method will be used when the object is non-const. It is possible to guide the compiler by:

```
const vector<double>& test = const_cast<Foo const&>(foo).V();
```

Or possibly nicer solution is to have the constant method have different name (eg.: `ConstV`). Or you can just add this new method and leave the current method there. This approach is used in C++0x standard. For example constant methods `cbegin()` and `cend()` have been added to standard containers.

Comment: Hooray for safe use of `const_cast`

Comment: Incorrect answer. `const_cast<Foo const>(foo)` creates a temporary, and `V()` is called on the temporary.

Comment: You probably meant `const_cast<Foo const&>(foo)` (`const_cast` expects a pointer or reference). Better yet is to use `static_cast`.

Comment: @Nawaz, @Luc Danton: Thanks, corrected. But it would work probably the same in this case. The temporary is only read so, there should be no problem in that.

Answer (score 5):

Overload resolution does not take member accessibility into account, so an ideal overload candidate is chosen and *then* member accessibility is checked to see if the call is legal.

The realistic workaround is:

```
Foo foo;
Foo const& foo_alias = foo;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i != foo_alias.V().size(); ++i)
    cout << foo_alias.V().at(i) << endl;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `const vector<double>& v = foo.V()` call be ok then ? In that only the public method returns a const vector ?
Thank you.

Comment: @foo : No, that implies that the fact that you want to bind the return value to a `const&` should matter, but overload resolution also does not take into account a function's return type.

Comment: @foo: The initializer expression is `foo.V()`; there's nothing `const` in there. (After the call is made, *then* it gets `const` tagged onto it.)

Answer (score 2):

Since `foo` is not `const` compiler is trying to use the non-const method. As a workaround you can do the following:

```
    Foo foo;
    const Foo& cFoo = foo;
    for(int i = 0; i < (int) cFoo.V().size(); ++i)
    cout << cFoo.V().at(i) << endl;
```

Comment: You could have used `size_t` in the `for` loop, instead of casting in `(int)cFoo.V().size()`. After all, `at()` takes parameter of type `size_type` which is most likely `size_t`, or *unsigned* integral type.

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution. The compiler will select the `const` function if the Foo is also `const`.

```
Foo foo;
const Foo& cfoo = foo; 

for(int i = 0; i < (int) cfoo.V().size(); ++i)
    cout << cfoo.V().at(i) << endl;
```